# Differential equation of chemical rate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've received this equation and was asked to compare my manual solution with the computer aided. This is the formula for the chemical rate equation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 7130(0.0010-x)^2(0.0041- (x/2))$$

By applying IVP, $x(0)=0$,
I get $c = 18.865$.

And after substituting $C$ in the equation after differential process I get the answer as the picture attached
[image: The manual solution]

The problem came when checking with the python, the answer we get is this
[image: The python solution]

We got different answer between manual solution and computer aided solution.

What did I do wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's kinda hard to say what you did wrong if you don't tell us what you did aka how you got the solution...